# multiple alarms calling same service

Tags: android, service, location, alarmmanager

I have multiple alarms calling broadcast intent which in turns calls a location service. The idea is to get location at separate timings. Location service takes some time to return location after which its shuts down. 
I was wondering what will happen in a case when 2 alarms call this common location service at same time or say alarm 1 already called location service and within a second alarm 2 also called location service, because i have read services have only 1 instance.

Also whats the best way to handle cases like the one i have mentioned above ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationView.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

In my NotificationView.class i call the service

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MyLocationService.class);
    context.startService(serviceIntent); //start service for get location
```

There can be multiple alarms scheduled within a difference of some secods calling this same service through this pending intent.

Comment: post your code. I think the problem is your pendingIntents should contains different requestCodes, when you put them into Broadcast

Comment: @АндройдАндройд updated. Also even if change request code, service will remain same right ? called through separate pending intents. How will that be handled ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you right. I show my code, where my request code is `i` variable. You can change it for you

```
public static void setAlarmReceiver(Context context, ArrayList<CheckPoint> checkPoints) {

        clearAlarmReceiver(context);

        if (checkPoints.size() == 0)
            return;

        int i = 0;
        for (CheckPoint checkPoint : checkPoints) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CheckAlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("checkPoint", checkPoint);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.valueOf(getDay(checkPoint.getDate())));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.valueOf(getMonth(checkPoint.getDate())) - 1);
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.valueOf(getYear(checkPoint.getDate())));
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(getHour(checkPoint.getCheckInTime())));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(getMinute(checkPoint.getCheckInTime())));
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            } else {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }

            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also pay attention for alarmManager.setExact and alarmManager.set

Comment: I know this thing but what if all these seprate alarms calls a common service at same time. How will service handle that ? Would separate instances be created because i dont think it is allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best solution it is create helper class that would be cache location and prevent additional call to service for example.

```
public class LocationHelper {
  public static AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Long, Location> cache = null; //location stored here
  public static int expiryTime = 5000; // 5 seconds for example

  private static boolean requested = false;

  private static List<LocationListener> callbacks = new ArrayList<>();// request heap

  public static void getLocation(LocationManager lm, LocationListener ll){
    Long currentTimeStamp = getTimeStamp();
    final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
       @Override
       public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
         cache = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(getTimeStamp(), location);

         synchronized(LocationHelper.class){
           for(LocationListener loclist : callbacks){
             loclist.onLocationChanged(location); // call each listener
           }
           callbacks.clear(); 
           requested = false;
         }
       }
    };
    if (cache != null && currentTimeStamp - cache.getKey() < expiryTime){
      ll.onLocationChanged(cache.getValue());
    } else {
       if(!requested){
         synchronized(LocationHelper.class){ // synchronize class to prevent thread collision and additional request
           if(!requested){
             lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME, LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
             requested = true;
           }
         }
       } else {
         synchronized(LocationHelper.class){
           callbacks.add(ll);
         }
       }
    }
  }

  public static Long getTimeStamp(){/*some code here*/}
}
```

this solution is a bit complex but it should work